# Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1570

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I try to add an Album using Core Data.

Album+CoreDataProperties.swift:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension Album {

@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Album> {
    return NSFetchRequest<Album>(entityName: "Album")
}

@NSManaged public var name: String

}
```

ViewController.swift

```
private func saveAlbum(){

    let appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let album = Album(context:context)
    album!.name = "Nature"
    if album?.name != nil {
        do {
            try context.save()
            print("Saved Product: \(String(describing: album!.name))")
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }catch let error {
            print("Error Saving: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

[xcdatamodel Entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzCsK.png)

[xcdatamodel Attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNUAk.png)

It should work since it's obvious the name is not nil.

Expected Result:

> Saved Product: Nature

But instead I got the error:

> Error Saving: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1570 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.)" UserInfo={NSValidationErrorObject= (entity: Album; id: 0x6000030c64c0  ; data: {
>       name = nil;
>   }), NSValidationErrorKey=name, NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.)}

Comment: Someone down voted the question without explanation. If you down vote the question at least explain why.

Comment: I didn’t down vote but some pointers, you didn’t add any context so we have to guess what the code is doing, you didn’t tell us at what line the error happens so we have to guess. Also not as serious but writing a good title to your question is also appreciated.

Comment: I thought it was clear. The func is for saving into core data.  Album have only one field Name. It should save "Nature" into the table Album, but I get the error that name is nil.

Comment: I edited and added more info to make it clearer.

Comment: It was kind of clear if you looked really carefully but it never hurts to try to explain as much as possible in writing when you post a question, if the reader doesn’t understand the question after a first quick read he/she might just move on to the next question (or down vote)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the entity in the xcdatamodel and created a new one with a different name. After changing the func in the viewcontroller and recreating the NSManagedObject Subclass it worked.

Comment: Still don't know what caused the problem, but this is a working solution.

Comment: You had Codegen set to manual for your entity, maybe something wasn’t rebuilt properly after you made some changes. Cleaning the project is always a good first step when you make a change to the core data model and run into unexpected issues and of course when you have set codegen to manual you must remember to re-generate your classes yourself.

Comment: Is the checkbox for `Optional` checked for your new entity attribute? It was not checked for your old entity attribute. It was likely that you were trying to set a non-optional attribute value to an optional in Swift via `album!.name =`